# Running count of specified value at or before row. Not consecutive count

Tags: r, count, dataframe, cumulative-sum

I have a data frame with variable `v1`. I want a variable `v2` to be the running count of zeros at the row (i.e. only count zeros at and before that row). Conversley, I'd like `v3` to be the running count of non-zero numbers.  The data frame `dat` illustrate the desired output.

```
dat <- structure(list(v1 = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 10L, 
2L, 0L), v2 = c(1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L
), v3 = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 6L)), .Names = c("v1", 
"v2", "v3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -12L))

> dat
   v1 v2 v3
1   0  1  0
2   0  2  0
3   1  2  1
4   0  3  1
5   0  4  1
6   0  5  1
7   1  5  2
8   1  5  3
9   1  5  4
10 10  5  5
11  2  5  6
12  0  6  6
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use `cumsum` here, for the cumulative sum(s) of a given condition.

```
> v1 <- c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 10, 2, 0)
> v2 <- cumsum(v1 == 0)
> v3 <- cumsum(v1 > 0)
> data.frame(v1, v2, v3)
##    v1 v2 v3
## 1   0  1  0
## 2   0  2  0
## 3   1  2  1
## 4   0  3  1
## 5   0  4  1
## 6   0  5  1
## 7   1  5  2
## 8   1  5  3
## 9   1  5  4
## 10 10  5  5
## 11  2  5  6
## 12  0  6  6
```

Answer (score 2):

```
within(dat, {
  v33 <- cumsum(v1 != 0)
  v22 <- cumsum(v1 == 0)
})

#    v1 v2 v3 v22 v33
# 1   0  1  0   1   0
# 2   0  2  0   2   0
# 3   1  2  1   2   1
# 4   0  3  1   3   1
# 5   0  4  1   4   1
# 6   0  5  1   5   1
# 7   1  5  2   5   2
# 8   1  5  3   5   3
# 9   1  5  4   5   4
# 10 10  5  5   5   5
# 11  2  5  6   5   6
# 12  0  6  6   6   6
```